# Multi-column search in lov of oracle forms developer 6i

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have created a LOV using query; It has 3 columns. When LOV is displayed I want to search a value. But when I type something it search only first column. LOV do not search in other columns except first column.

Is there anybody who knows how to search any value of other column or multi-column search in forms developer 6i?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An Oracle Forms LOV only searches the first column - so you might need to concatenate 2 or more columns into the first column to get what you want.

Otherwise, you may need to make your own custom LOV form.

Comment: Thanks Kemp for your comments. By the way would you have any reference of creating custom lov form?

Comment: Sorry, no - it's just an ordinary form. It would probably have a single data block based on a table, and maybe checkboxes to allow the user to select one or more rows, and a button to return the selected id to the calling form via a global variable.